Can the observable mass within the observable universe be estimated without using $G$?
The estimation of the baryonic mass of the observable universe can be done through its density parameter and the critical density, which depends on the gravitational constant $G$.
Is there a way to measure or estimate the mass of the observable universe without the gravitational constant? For instant, by direct observation?
I assume it could be derived from the total luminosity and the average mass to light ratio of the universe.

We can't even determine the masses of bodies in the Solar System without G. I have some info in https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/48616/16685

Of course we can.
And we have a cute name for the difference between the estimation of the baryonic mass WITHOUT $G$ and the estimation of the baryonic mass WITH $G$: it is called dark matter.

But the calculation of baryonic mass within LCDM involves G, particularly in the critical density. I am curious about direct measurements.
